# Как происходит отслеживание источника перехода по ссылке?

Tags: php, javascript, html, веб-программирование

Откуда берет значение $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] PHP и в принципе аналогичные функции,  какие вообще бывают алгоритмы отслеживание источника перехода?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переменная $_SERVER - это массив, содержащий информацию, такую как заголовки, пути и местоположения скриптов. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] - Адрес страницы (если есть), которая привела браузер пользователя на эту страницу. **Этот заголовок устанавливается веб-браузером пользователя.** Не все браузеры устанавливают его и некоторые в качестве дополнительной возможности позволяют изменять содержимое заголовка HTTP_REFERER. **Одним словом, в самом деле ему нельзя доверять.** 
http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php